# spark-scala-mongo-aggregate: query multiple fields and group by 2 fields

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, aggregation-framework

I'm looking for mongo aggregation code example that queries multiple fields from a collection and groups by a couple of fields. My collection:

```
events:
{
_id
prodId:
location:
status:
user:
date:
}
```

The above collection is very flat. I'm Looking for Results like the below:

```
For status "Completed" (This is a $match condition)

    {Product: abc
         {Location: US
            {user, date}
            {user, date
            {user, date}
             .......}
         {Location: APAC
            {user, date}
            {user, date
            {user, date}
             .......}}
    {Product: XYZ
         {Location: US
            {user, date}
            {user, date
            {user, date}
             .......}
         {Location: APAC
            {user, date}
            {user, date
            {user, date}
             .......}}
  ........
```

How do we write this in aggregation framework using nested `$group` and `$match` or any other aggregation stages..

Any advise or help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trail and error, I was able to resolve this to a certain extent. Though, it is not exactly what i was looking for, but this is better. Here is what I got.

```
{
        "_id" : {
                "Product" : "ABC",
                "location" : "ERU"
        },
        "details" : [
                {   //Each of this is a unique combination
                        "user" : "XXXX",
                        "date" : ISODate("2015-08-01T09:08:15Z")
                },
                {
                        "user" : "xxxx",
                        "date" : ISODate("2015-08-01T09:03:08Z")
                },
                {
                        "user" : "xxxx",
                        "date" : ISODate("2015-07-20T19:33:57Z")
                },
                {
                        "user" : "xxxx",
                        "date" : ISODate("2015-07-20T19:28:50Z")
                }
        ],
        "count" : 4
}
{
        "_id" : {
                "Product" : "AAA",
                "location" : "US"
        },
        "details" : [
                {
                        "user" : "XXXX",
                        "date" : ISODate("2015-08-01T09:08:15Z")
                },
                {
                        "user" : "xxxx",
                        "date" : ISODate("2015-08-01T09:03:08Z")
                },
                {
                        "user" : "xxxx",
                        "date" : ISODate("2015-07-20T19:33:57Z")
                },
                {
                        "user" : "xxxx",
                        "date" : ISODate("2015-07-20T19:28:50Z")
                }
        ],
        "count" : 4
}
```

My aggregation code:

```
db.events.aggregate([
 {$project: 
    {
        ProdId:1,
        location:1,
        username:1,
        status:1,
        dateTime:1
    }
    }
, {$group: 
    {
        _id: {Product: "$prodId", location: "$location"},
        details: {$addToSet: {user: "$username", date: "$dateTime"}},
        count: {$sum: 1}
    }}
],{allowDiskUse: true}
)
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use group with multiple fields as this :

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$group: {attr1:'$attr1', attr2:'$attr2'}}])
```

Comment: Camille: Thanks for getting back to me. I have edited my post with more realistic collection fields and what I need to achieve. I'm looking for the aggregation code. currently i have gotten this far. I'm limiting the location to US for now to reduce the dataset. `db.events.aggregate([
{$match: {$and: [
    {location: 'US'},
    {status:'end'},
    {prodId:{$ne:null}},
    {user:{$ne:null}}
    ]}}
, {$group: 
 {
  _id: "$prodId",
  users: {$push: "$user"}
 }},
 {$out : "eventProdUsersAgg"}
],{allowDiskUse: true}
)`. But this is only giving me a set of users for a product.

Comment: How do I change this to get location and date and in the format that i mentioned in my post?